# Proving the trisection of a side of a triangle

Tags: geometry, solution-verification, euclidean-geometry

> In $\triangle ABC$, let $M$ and $N$ be the midpoint of $\overline{AB}$ and $\overline{CM}$, respectively. Prove that extending $\overline{AN}$ towards $\overline{BC}$ trisects $\overline{BC}$.

This is Exercise 125.1 from *Calculus with Analytic Geometry* by Peterson. The instruction is to prove it using vectors, however, I want to try using basic geometry only.

*Proof*. Make $\triangle ABC$ a parallelogram by reflecting $C$ on $\overline{AB}$. Call this point $C'$. Also, let the intersection of $\overset{\longrightarrow}{AN}$ and $BC$ be $P$. Then, $\angle ANC' \cong \angle PNC$ by the Vertical Angles Theorem. Also, $\angle C'AN \cong \angle CPN$ and $AC'N \cong \angle PCN$ by the Alternate Interior Angles Theorem. By the $AA$ similarity rule, $\triangle C'AN \sim \triangle PCN$.

Because parallelogram $AC'BC$ is made by reflecting $C$ on $\overline{AB}$, then $\overline{AB}$ must be a diagonal, and $\overline{CM} \cong \overline{C'M} \implies CM = C'M$. Because $N$ is the midpoint of $CM$, then $CN = \frac{1}{2}CM$. This means that $C'N = CM + \frac{1}{2}CM = \frac{3}{2}CM$.

The similarity of $\triangle AC'N$ and $\triangle PCN$ implies that $$\frac{PC}{AC'} = \frac{CN}{C'N}$$. By substitution,
\begin{align*}\frac{PC}{AC'} &= \frac{\frac{1}{2}CM}{\frac{3}{2}CM} \\ \frac{PC}{AC'} &= \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{2}{3} \\ \frac{PC}{AC'} &= \frac{1}{3}\end{align*}

As $BC = AC'$, this means that $CP$ is one-third of $CB$. Therefore, extending $\overline{AN}$ towards $\overline{BC}$ will trisect $\overline{BC}$.

---

Is my proof correct? If so, what should be done to simplify it further?

*Please, if my proof is correct and my proof can be simplified further, please, post it as an answer, not a comment. Some of my questions tagging* [solution-verification](/questions/tagged/solution-verification) *are left in the [Unanswered](https://math.stackexchange.com/unanswered) section. I should also probably check [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20097) and [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16355).*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is completely correct. But all those constructions could be avoided by just applying Menelaus Theorem on $\triangle BCM$ considering $ANP$ as the transversal.

Comment: Oh. I forgot about that theorem. I guess I have to start reviewing again.